# Benchmarking CoreData and Realm

Tags: ios, core-data, realm

How can I properly benchmark CoreData and Realm?

I've used Unit Testing and it took more time for the Realm database to add 100,000 records of data compared to CoreData (which I believe is incorrect) and no I didn't use InMemory because I'm concerned with the benchmarks being as close to reality as possible.

So what's the proper way to benchmark database fetch/add/remove processes? XCTest? Instruments?

If XCTest is the way, then I must've been testing it wrong. I believe Realm should outperform CoreData in at least simple databases.

Answer (score 0):

Some general benchmarking questions:

1. What compiler optimization level are you building with? Building in "Release" mode with full optimizations is the best optimization setting will likely be the closest match to real world behavior that you're seeing.
2. Are you benchmarking in the simulator or on a real device? It's critical to test on a real iOS device.
3. How close does your benchmark code reflect real-world usage? Synthetic benchmarks are often misleading unless great care is taken to reflect how libraries are actually used in reality. For example, Realm's per-transaction overhead is likely higher than Core Data's because it preserves *isolation* (the "I" in ACID: e.g. no faults in Realm). But writes within a transaction are likely faster than Core Data. Most queries will be faster in Realm, especially graph traversals. Are you creating lots of small transactions, or few large ones? All of this impacts performance characteristics.
4. Are you accidentally measuring unrelated code in your benchmarks? I have to ask, you'd be surprised at some of the benchmark code I've seen spending most of its time in `NSLog`...

Finally, XCTest and Instruments shouldn't drastically affect a benchmark comparison in most situations. I'd actually encourage you to look at Instruments though to confirm #4.